# C++ template matrix class - square matrix specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, static

I'm creating a simple C++ matrix template class, with the following definition:

```cpp
template<uint n, uint m, typename T = double>
class Matrix {
private:
    T data[n][m];

    static Matrix<n, m, T> I;

public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> l);

    T& at(uint i, uint j);  // one-based index
    T& at_(uint i, uint j); // zero-based index

    template<uint k> Matrix<n, k, T> operator*(Matrix<m, k, T>& rhs);
    Matrix<m, n, T> transpose();
    Matrix<n, m, T> operator+(const Matrix<n, m, T>& rhs);
    Matrix<n, m, T>& operator+=(const Matrix<n, m, T>& rhs);
    Matrix<n, m, T> operator-(const Matrix<n, m, T>& rhs);
    Matrix<n, m, T>& operator-=(const Matrix<n, m, T>& rhs);
    Matrix<n, m, T> operator*(const T& rhs);
    Matrix<n, m, T>& operator*=(const T& rhs);
    Matrix<n, m, T> operator/(const T& rhs);
    Matrix<n, m, T>& operator/=(const T& rhs);

    static Matrix<n, m, T> identity();
};
```

(`uint` is defined as an `unsigned int`)

The final function `Matrix<n, m, T> identity()` aims to return the static `I` member which is the identity matrix using a basic singleton pattern. Obviously the identity matrix is only defined for square matrices so I tried this:

```cpp
template<uint n, typename T>
inline Matrix<n, n, T> Matrix<n, n, T>::identity() {
    if (!I) {
        I = Matrix<n, n, T>();
        for (uint i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            I.at(i, i) = 1;
        }
    }
    return I;
}
```

Which gives the error `C2244 'Matrix<n,n,T>::identity': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration`.

My impression was that I could do some sort of specialisation of the template where the number of columns and rows are equal. I'm not sure if this is even possible, but your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static Matrix<n, m> identity() {
    static_assert(n == m, "Only square matrices have a identity");
    return {}; //TODO
}
```

See: http://cpp.sh/7te2z

Comment: That won't work. Instantiating `Matrix` with n != m will result in instantiating the function signature, which is ill-formed when n != m. You have to be a bit more subtle.

Comment: @Brian you're right, it doesn't compile. I don't understand why SFINAE doesn't kick in and just ignores the function. Anyway, edited my answer, static_assert seems to work and even gives a better error-message

Comment: SFINAE only occurs when substitution failure occurs during template argument deduction.

Comment: Thanks, I've not not really come across static_assert :)

Answer (score -1):

[Partial specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) of a template class is allowed for the entire class, but not for its single member.

> Members of partial specializations are not related to the members of the primary
>   template.

That is the reason behind your compilation error.

Of course, specializing the entire Matrix template for the square matrix case doesn't make sense. [@tkausl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080064/tkausl) has already answered how to make the `identity()` function available only for the square matrix types.

However, I would like to draw your attention toward a couple of issues in your implementation of `Matrix`:

1. The matrix data is a plain array (instead of a dynamically allocated array or `std::vector`). This has the following disadvantages:

   - `sizeof(Matrix<N, M, T>) == sizeof(T)*N*M`. Allocating large matrices on the stack may result in [stack overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).
   - Impossibility of taking advantage of move semantics (as the data is inseparable from the matrix object).

   Though, if the matrix dimensions are fixed at compile time constants, then, most probably, they will be small numbers. If so, paying the cost of dynamic allocation may indeed be unjustified.
2. `identity()` returns its result by value (rather than by constant reference).
3. `I` (the identity matrix) is a static member of the class. It is better to make it a static variable inside the `identity()` function.